# creating or changing UIimage from a DIFFERENT Class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to create or change a UIimage from another class using a class method. however when I try to address the view in the class controller I can't. e.g. [self.view addsubview:...] is this possible ? what would be the best way to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You import the header file of your UIImage (or better use UIIMageView) in the second class, then define it as an object. Add @property and @synthesize is the second .m. The reference shoul work after as addSubview will know about imported object.

Comment: Ok will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this is your model class header file and you define your uiimageview:

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *modelImageView;
```

and this is your view controller and its implementation file you may use like this:

```
#import "YourModel.h"
@interface yourViewController() {
YourModel *yourModel;
}
end
@implementation yourViewController
- (void) viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.view addSubView:yourModel.modelImageView];
}@end
```

That was straight way to do and to make something better; just define some methods which controls your `UIImageView`like changeColor setBackgroundColor etc. and reach them from your viewController just using for example:

```
[yourModel setColor:[UIColor greenColor] placeHolderImage:[UIImage ...]];
```

So what I'm trying to explain in here you can reach your UIImageView wherever you want and you will just have one Model is reachable from every viewController.

Comment: Thanks for responding but I think I didnt explain clearly I have two classes one of which contains the uiimageview, viewcontroller.m but I want to set it from secondcontroller.m

Comment: Okey I get it now but usually its bad idea to reach from one view to another.I recommend you to research MVC architecture and if you explain what you want to do with that imageview I can edit my answer regarding your exact question. :)

Comment: I forgot to mention sorry.in your case, MVVM may be a better choice than MVC.

Comment: ok I think I have it now but what I am doing is calling the class method from another class and calling the private method using a shared instance. is that bad to do or is that ok ?  in .m= static parser *sharedInstance = nil;      sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL]init];  [sharedInstance hello] ; calling -(void)hello;

Comment: It seems okay but be sure that you are not allocating it twice but it might be a better if you use dispatch_once(). For further information you may examine this: http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.it/2011/04/singletons-your-doing-them-wrong.html